# What does the 100BASE-FC mean and what is the answer to the following

Tags: networking

What does the 100BASE-FC mean and what is the answer to the following

- router and a switch, which is used to connect networks together?

my friend say  switch

i say router

well what the difference, some where it say switch used to connect this and that, some where it say router...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"100BASE-FC" doesn't seem to exist. Best I can tell it's a [100BASE-FX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Ethernet#100BASE-FX) adapter with a [FC connector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FC_connector).

Routers are used to connect two different networks. Switches are used to connect multiple segments of the same network. Routers work at a slightly higher level in the OSI model than switches, which lets them inspect packets more deeply and route them appropriately.